Receive error code 0Eh and 00h from Mifare Ultralight Ev1 128 bytes NFC tag
I don't know the reason why I received a strange code from the tag!
Currently, from the app's logs on production of my application, I see a lot of response code 0Eh and 00h. I captured some logs: They're all write commands and the page to write could be a user memory page or maybe other pages such as pwd, pack, mod,...
cmd: A22053757474 -> response: 0E
cmd: A20900000000 -> response: 0E
cmd: A227AB776580 -> response: 0E
cmd: A20C00000000 -> response: 0E
cmd: A20B40590000 -> response: 0E
cmd: A20B40690000 -> response: 0E

the code to write data is just sent command from readers to tag, and return the response
I'm using some third-party SDK, they also confirmed that 0Eh is from the tag
I checked the documentation and there's no description about 0Eh error code. See also:NFC document
